# Radially symmetric solutions of the Dirichlet problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dirichlet-series

How do I find the radially symmetric solutions of this Dirichlet problem?

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
u_{tt} + u_{yy} = (x^2+y^2)^2 & \quad  \mbox{ on $1< x^2 + y^2< 4\ $,} \\
\quad u(x,y) = 3 & \quad  \mbox{ on $ x^2 + y^2 = 4\ $}, \\
\quad u(x,y) = 2 & \quad \mbox{ on $ x^2 + y^2 = 1\ $}
\end{array} 
\right. $$

Answer (score 0):

Solve
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
u_{xx} + u_{yy} = (x^2+y^2)^2 & \quad  \mbox{ on $1< x^2 + y^2< 4\ $,} \\
\quad u(x,y) = 3 & \quad  \mbox{ on $ x^2 + y^2 = 4\ $}, \\
\quad u(x,y) = 2 & \quad \mbox{ on $ x^2 + y^2 = 1\ $}
\end{array} 
\right.$$

- Let $u=v(x^2+y^2)$. Then
  $$u_x=v'(x^2+y^2)\,2\,x$$
  $$u_{xx}=v''(x^2+y^2)\,4\,x^2+2v'(x^2+y^2)$$ 
  $$u_y=v'(x^2+y^2)\,2\,y$$
  $$u_{yy}=v''(x^2+y^2)\,4\,y^2+2v'(x^2+y^2)$$
  $$u_{xx} + u_{yy}=4v''(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2)+4v'(x^2+y^2)$$
- Let $t=x^2+y^2$. We have ODE problem
  $$4v''(t)t+4v'(t)=t^2,\;v(4)=3,\; v(1)=2.
  $$
- Solution is
  $$v=-\frac{3\log(t)}{4\log(4)}+\frac{t^3}{36}+\frac{71}{36}.$$
- Answer:
  $$u=-\frac{3\log(x^2+y^2)}{4\log(4)}+\frac{(x^2+y^2)^3}{36}+\frac{71}{36}.$$